# Spring scheduler tasks causes memory leak in tomcat

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, tomcat6, scheduler, rhino

I have used spring scheduler to run methods using a cron timer as shown below . The application has atleast 50 scheduler beans of the same class mentioned in bold below. We create new beans by passing configuration parameters through an xml given in the property section. But we get an error from tomcat 6.0.36 which is shown as italics text below. Is this an issue , is there any way to overcome this error. If we add a lot of scheduled tasks as given below , will this not affect the application performance?

***SEVERE: The web application [/App ] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@757fad]) and a value of type [org.mozilla.javascript.Context[]] (value [[Lorg.mozilla.javascript.Context;@18e915a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.***

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="taskSchedulerClass" method="callScheduler" cron="0 0/4 * * * *"/> </task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

**<bean id="taskSchedulerClass" class="com.abc.efg.util.xyz">**
     <property name="xmlName" value="xyz.xml" />  </bean>
```

Comment: Memory leak will eventually occur When you will deploy/undeploy your webapp. Anyway this leak does not seem related to your tasks but with mozilla context. Do you use Rhino or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Rhino's context clean up has been improved only for tomcat 7 : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49159 . So you will still get in tomcat6. Your error does not seem related to your scheduler.